# external boot efi shell when secure boot is turned on

Tags: boot, uefi, secure-boot

I don't have a built in uefi shell in my laptop and I have secure boot turned on.
I would be happy for a signed uefi shell that I can boot into (edk2, tianocore shell.efi files are not signed and I cannot load them when secure boot is on).

And no, I cannot turn off secure boot.

Comment: anyone has any idea ?